# C# faculty : weird results

Tags: c#

i tried to write an easy code to output a result from a faculty.
(presuming the user entered a positive number)
so for example: input 5. So
5! = 5*4*3*2*1 = 120
if i enter a low number, the result is correct, but when i enter for example 24, i get a negative number !??! 
who can sort this out ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //input
        Console.WriteLine("you want to calculate the faculty from which number ?");
        string inputString;
        inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        int inputInt;
        inputInt = Convert.ToInt32(inputString);
        int i;
        int result;
        result = 1;
        //
        for (i = inputInt ; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            result = result * i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(inputInt + "! = " + result);
        //
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: `int` = 32-bit *signed* number. Your calculation overflowed.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315388/multiplying-two-positive-int32-returns-incorrect-negative-answer for the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab > Advanced button > tick the "Check for arithmetic overflow" option.  Should be turned on for any project in the Debug configuration, that the project template does not do this is a great oversight.

Comment: thanks! i love this website, really quick and usefull help over here!

Answer (score 5):

You are getting an [Integer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

int is a 32-bit signed integer, meaning that it can contain any value between -2^31 and 2^31 - 1. Meaning the biggest value it can store is around 2 billion, or 10 digits. 24! is a 24 digit number.

Comment: true but 24! is not a 24 digit number. thats not like n! means n digit number

Comment: Then, by all means, tell me how many digits you think 24! has.

Comment: The formula and its proven [here](http://pitcher.digitalfreehold.ca/code/computeSize) is `Ceiling[log(N) +log (N-1) ... +log(1)]` . im not a mathematician i just googled it

Comment: And if you were to plug 24 into your pretty little formula...?

Comment: ok ok. 24 digits. +1 but i just wanted to mention n! doesn't necessarily mean n digit number. you are the mathematician :)

Answer (score 4):

Your calculation getting overflowed. Since int is 32 bit signed number so when you try to store a value larger than that it will be overflowed.

You can try to have a look at [BigInteger Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) which can be used to store large values.

For example

```
var x = new BigInteger(1);
var fact = 171;
for (var i = 1; i <= fact; i++)
{
    x*= i;
}
```

will give output as

1241018070217667823424840524103103992616605577501693185388951803611996075221691752992751978120487585576464959501670387052809889858690710767331242032218484364310473577889968548278290754541561964852153468318044293239598173696899657235903947616152278558180061176365108428800000000000000000000000000000000000000000