# Calculating factorial using user input - console application

Tags: c#, console-application, calculation

Edited: pasted the correct code this time...

I'm trying to calculate a factorial of a number. In this example, I enter the number 5.

Trying this method, gives me a huge negative number:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int consoleInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());            

        for (int i = 1; i < consoleInput; i++)
        {
            consoleInput = consoleInput * i;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(consoleInput);
    }
```

Outputs `-1899959296`

However:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int consoleInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int result = consoleInput;

        for (int i = 1; i < consoleInput; i++)
        {
            result = result * i;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Outputs `120`

If I enter 5 both times, the first time the output is -1899959296 and the second time, the output is 120.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: `int` is too small.

Comment: I do not see any difference in the two programs, but most likely the answer is greater than `int.MaxValue` and you are overflowing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiplying two positive Int32 returns incorrect, negative answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315388/multiplying-two-positive-int32-returns-incorrect-negative-answer)

Comment: What is the difference between the two codes? A mistake perhaps?

Comment: I enter 5 both times.

The first time the output is: -1899959296
The second time the output is: 120

Comment: Might be overkill, but replace `int` with `ulong`.

Comment: Replacing `int` with `ulong` and the first method now prints 0 hmm

Comment: Please learn to use the debugger. Step through the loop and see what the values of `i` and `consoleLoop` are to see why the first method is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you change '`consoleInput`' in each loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < consoleInput; i++)
        {
            consoleInput = consoleInput * i;
        }
```

Now the '`for`' checks against a new value every time.

The reason it gets negative is an overflow condition.

**Edit**:

The reason it gets so large, is because the loop 'never' ends, since the value you check against grows on every loop.

Comment: Makes sense, but how can the number get so large for 5 loops?

Comment: @PoulBak the loop will end after the first overflow since `i` will be greater then `consoleResult` (which is negative).

Comment: @D Stanley, that is correct (I put 'never' in quotes for that reason).